# PowerShell script to upgrade PowerShell version

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have PowerShell script which required PowerShell version 4.0 so i want to write PowerShell script to upgrade version of PowerShell to 4.0 so client can use easily.

Comment: Sounds doable. Have at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download the zip with WMF5.1 from Microsoft Website, it already includes a Powershell install script. No need to reinvent the wheel.